# iPhone NSURLConnection: What to do with returned NSData Object? Google Docs API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I'm working with the Google Docs API in my iPhone application.  I've sent the proper POST request, and received a response along with some NSData.  If I NSLog the NSData object, I get this:

```
NSData *returnedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:theResponse error:NULL];
NSLog(@"%@",returnedData);
//output : <4572726f 723d4261 64417574 68656e74 69636174 696f6e0a>
```

I think the NSData is either an NSDictionary or an NSArray.  I'm supposed to receive a couple of items back, an SID, an LSID, and an Auth.

If I could turn the NSData chunk into an NSDictionary I could just find the object for whichever key.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The selected answer is what worked.  Google returns plain/text format, encoded in NSUTF8StringEncoding

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to decode the data. Try the following:

```
NSString *result= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Of course this will depend on how the data is encoded. NSUTF8StringEncoding might work instead.

Comment: The selected answer is what worked.  Now I'm going to ask another question!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955990/iphone-google-data-api-http-protocol-auth-token-from-string

FREE POINTS TO THE FIRST GREAT ANSWER!

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to pass the data to an NSXMLParser

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with web data is Doing NSXML parsing. No need of decoding data the parser will handle itself