# iPhone Google Data API HTTP Protocol, Auth Token from string

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine, nsstring

Google Docs returns a long 3 line string when supplied with credentials. This is the format 
    SID=stuff...
    LSID=stuff...
    Auth=long authorization token

if I have it stored in NSString, what is the best function to trim all the way up to the "=" behind Auth, and keep the rest?

```
NSData *returnedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:theResponse error:NULL];
NSString *newDataString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *authToken = [newDataString ____________];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer on my own through the documentation for NSString:

there is a method called
    -(NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)separator {

that gives back an array of different strings, separated by an NSCharacterSet.

There is a class method of NSCharacterSet called

+(NSCharacterSet *)newLineCharacterSet {

that will split up a string with the newline symbol into pieces, so each line becomes  its own object.  Here is how it works:

```
NSData *returnedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:NULL];
NSString *newDataString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSCharacterSet *theCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
NSArray *lineArray = [newDataString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:theCharacterSet];
```

Now, the object lineArray contains different strings, each one is the start of a new line.

You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If it is a three-line string, I assume it is split with newline (`\n`) characters.

```
NSArray *_authComponents = [threeLineString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSString *_sidToken = [_authComponents objectAtIndex:0]; // "SID=..."
NSString *_lsidToken = [_authComponents objectAtIndex:1]; // "LSID=..."
NSString *_authToken = [_authComponents objectAtIndex:2]; // "Auth=..."
```

Hopefully that gets you started. Once you have individual components, you can repeat on the equals (`=`) character, for example.